# Only logging NaN, although variables are declared and initialized

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am sorry for this naive question. I have this simple timer and I am not a hundred percent sure what is going wrong here. I want to display a number like 7 : 10 : 20.

```
let running = false,
    showClock = false,
    time

let h, m, s
function timer() {
    s = s + 1
    m = Math.floor(s / 60)
    h = Math.floor(h / 60)
    time = `${h} : ${m} : ${s}`
    console.log(time)
}

function runClock() {

    running = !running
    showClock = !showClock
    let id
    if (running) {
        id = setInterval(timer, 1000)
    } else {
        clearInterval(id)
    }
}
```

I attach the `runClock`function to a onClick method and want to log the time. But it is fist only logging NaN : NaN : NaN and secondly it is not stopping. Anybody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What result do you expect from `s = undefined + 1;`?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Should I initialize s inside the `timer` function?

Comment: You should initialize it somewhere. In your code `s` is not initialized. You can fix it with `s = (s ?? 0) + 1;`

Comment: Sorry again for the qustion, but the line `let h, m, s` does not initialize s?

Comment: No, it doesn't initialize anything. It declares 3 variables and all 3 variables contain `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks ! You are right of course, it's too early...

Answer (score 1):

s is not initiliazed. You are trying to add 1 to undefined, which will cause NaN

Fix: initiliaze s before.

Comment: thanks a lot! But isn't it enough to initialize s outside the function?

Comment: Well, with initiliaze I mean actually assigning a value to it. You need to set it to something, else you cant do math with it.